# Asp.net CS1002 "; expected"

Tags: asp.net

Have this code. Breaks down with cs1002 exception: "Expected ;". What did i do wrong?

```
    <%
        foreach (var rubric in RubricTreeView.Nodes)
        { %>
            <div class="rubric-list-item top-level" data-id="<%rubric.Id%>">
                <span class="rubric-list-chb">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chb<%rubric.Id%>" />    
                    <label class="checkbox-skin" for="chb<%rubric.Id%>"></label>
                </span>
                <span class="rubric-list-marker active"></span>
                <%rubric.Title%>
            </div>
            <% if (rubric.SubNodes.Any())
               { %>
                      <div class="rubric-list-subitems">
                          <% foreach (var subRubric in rubric.SubNodes)
                             {%>
                                <div class="rubric-list-item active">
                                    <span class="rubric-list-chb">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chb<%subRubric.Id%>" />
                                        <label class="checkbox-skin" for="chb<%subRubric.Id%>"></label>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="rubric-list-marker"></span>
                                    <%subRubric.Title%>
                                </div>
                           <%} %>
                      </div>
            <% } %>
     <% } %>
```

Maybe <%subRubric.Title;%> ?

Comment: At what line does this error occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
<%= rubric.Title %>
```

and

```
<%= subRubric.Title %>
```

and in a few places

```
<%= rubric.Id %>
```

Else, the code inside will be evaluated as code block, meaning that it needs `;`.

Comment: Also <%=rubric.Id%> and <%=subRubric.Title%> - in other words properties should be used with <%= %>